# android AppBarLayout and BottomNavigationView elevation not working with darker colors

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set elevation to AppbarLayout and BottomNavigationView on Android. Unfortunately, both widgets totally ignore both `app:elevation` and `android:elevation` attributes. Interestingly enough, the app bar displays a shadow when I set it's background tint to `#fdd835`, which is my secondary colour, but when I set it to my primary (`#283593`), it suddenly stops working. When it *does* display the shadow, it still completely ignores the elevation attributes and displays the default shadow. The shadow also works with white or any lighter colour as background tint. It doesn't matter which theme I use, my AppBar theme is derived from `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar`. A similar thing happens with BottomNavigationView, only the shadow is displayed exclusively when the background colour is white.
My activity layout, containing the bottom navigation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="com.patlejch.timetables.ui.MainViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="MainViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="@{viewModel.insets.left}"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_host"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_main" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingBottom="@{viewModel.insets.bottom}"
            app:elevation="8dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorOnPrimary"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorOnPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

One of my fragments (it doesn't work on any of my fragments):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.patlejch.timetables.ui.home.HomeViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@{viewModel.insets.top}"
            android:theme="@style/AppBarLayoutTheme"
            android:backgroundTint="?colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
                onMenuClick="@{(item) -> viewModel.onMenuItemClicked(item)}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_home"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopupTheme"
                app:title="@{viewModel.dateFormatted}"
                tools:title="16 October 2019" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/home_appbar">

.....
```